# How to get actual child collection when updating parent

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, parent-child

How can I get actual child collection, when adding new one in separated transactional method, while updating parent.

I have spring boot app with hibernate/jpa and one-to-many unidirectional model:

parent:

```
@Entity
public class Deal {

    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Rate> rates;

    ....
}
```

child:

```
@Entity
public class Rate {

    private UUID id;
    
    ....
}
```

And I have non transactional method for do some business logic by rest call:

```
public Deal applyDeal(UUID dealId) {

    dealService.apply(dealId);
    return dealService.getById(dealId);
}
```

Method apply in DealService has several methods in separate transactions (all methods doLogic() annotated with @Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW):

```
public void apply(UUI dealId) {
    someService1.do1Logic(...);
    someService2.do2Logic(...);
    someService3.do3Logic(...);
}
```

In do2Logic() I have some logic that adding new Rate entity to my parent entity with dealId and direct call of save method for Deal object.

```
@Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
publid void do2Logic(...) {
    ...
    var deal = dealService.getById(...);
    deal.getRates().add(new Rate());
    dealService.save(deal);
}
```

But when I get response from root method applyDeal the new child entity is absent.
If after that I will try to get this parent in separate rest call (getDeal) I get actual parent entity with new child in collection.

**How to get actual child collection in parent response of `applyDeal` method?**

I tried to make all logic in one @Transactional but it doesn't works.
I also don't understand why when I am try to get deal instance to return in applyDeal I get old data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running MySQL or MariaDB? These two database by default use the repeatable read transaction isolation level, which can cause this behavior. Try configuring the read committed isolation level instead, and/or remove the `REQUIRES_NEW` propagation if possible, since that will suspend an already running transaction to start a second one.

Comment: I'm using PostgresSQL with repeatable read isolation level.
I'm also tried it with read committed level, but still not works.